# What's the best way to load a lot of images from multiple directories?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I currently use a really long and sloppy bit of code using `for X in range(len(os.listdir(...))`.

I typically use multiple directories to store images, so how could I load images faster?

Comment: That code looks fine to me...

Comment: The problem is that it's normally very very very long and I have to reiterate it each time I load new types of images. (sprites,backgrounds,etc.)

Comment: Can you get away with just the *appearance* of loading faster? For example, is it OK to display/manipulate/use some images while the others are still loading in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would investigate the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Perhaps you could use it to load and process multiple images at once?

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but still perfect! Kinda wish I knew that this was a thing for multiple other projects. Danke.